# How to quit a button event from clicking another button

Tags: python, pyqt5

My intention is to stop a function from running which relies on another button press from another button, I am unsure on what to add to the abort button function, any help would be appreciated.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 210, 91, 81))
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.sweepbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.sweepbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 210, 93, 81))
        self.sweepbutton.setObjectName("sweepbutton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        #self.button.clicked.connect()
        self.sweepbutton.clicked.connect(self.counter)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Abort"))
        self.sweepbutton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Counter"))

    def counter(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def interupt_counter(self):
    #unsure on how to interupt the counter when the user presses the button
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?
....

Comment: Post the code tried thus far.

Comment: Hey @DankDizaster, I have edited the thread on the code I have produced so far. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you need to run counter method in qthread.

Comment: @Hitobat, could you show me what I could possibly try (I’m new to PyQt)

Comment: @andyon98 I would say something like this example: https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/